# Visual studio C++ 20 module import .h&.cpp lib

Tags: c++, visual-studio, module, header-files, c++20

lib1 has two files

math.h

```
inline void hello();
```

and math.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "math.h"

void hello() {
    std::cout << "hello from math";
}
```

lib2 is a c++ 2a module lib:

```
export module Bar;

import "math.h";
import std.core;

export namespace bar {
    void BarFunc() { 
        hello();
    }
}
```

visual studio 16.8.0
compiler will say:(Bar.ixx.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl hello(void)" (?hello@@YAXXZ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

math.h

```
inline void hello();
```

to

```
void hello();
```

works.

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.

Answer (score -1):

Given the current information, I am afraid that I cannot determine the cause of the problem. So, I suggest that you could use [DUMPBIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2001?view=msvc-160) to help you find the cause.

> The [/EXPORTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dash-exports?view=msvc-160) and [/SYMBOLS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/symbols?view=msvc-160) options of the DUMPBIN command-line tool are
> useful here. They can help you discover which symbols are defined in
> your .dll and object or library files. You can use the symbols list to
> verify that the exported decorated names match the decorated names the
> linker searches for.
>
> In some cases, the linker can only report the decorated name for a
> symbol. You can use the UNDNAME command-line tool to get the
> undecorated form of a decorated name.

Comment: added. Not work.Is this a header unit or something?

Comment: I suggest that you could use `DUMPBIN`. Hope it will help you.